# Регулярные выражения. Ошибка в отборе ФИО

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

```
public class FullNameFormatterRegex {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        if (input.equals("0")) {
            scanner.close();
            break;
        }
        String regexp = "([А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+[\\-\\s]?){3,}";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        int summ = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
            if (input.charAt(i) >= '0' && input.charAt(i) <='9' || summ > 2 || summ==0){
                System.out.println("Введенная строка не является ФИО");
                break;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Фамилия: " + matcher.group(1));
                System.out.println("Имя:" + matcher.group(2));
                System.out.println("Отчество:" + matcher.group(3));
                break;
                }
            }
        }
    //TODO:напишите ваш код тут, результат вывести в консоль.
    //При невалидном ФИО вывести в консоль: Введенная строка не является ФИО
  }
}
```

При переборе ФИО (Салтыков-Щедрин Михаил Евграфович; Иванов Иван Иванович) Выдает "Введенная строка не является ФИО". Как задать граници через регулярные выражения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значение `summ` в цикле нигде не меняется, и сразу же выполняется условие `summ == 0`, по которому происходит выход из цикла.  Регулярное выражение для чего-то создаётся на каждой итерации цикла.  Также в регулярном выражении содержится только одна группа, соответственно попытка обратиться к группам 2 и 3 вызовет исключение.

Для проверки на ФИО в русском алфавите можно было бы использовать именованные группы, в которых следовало бы разрешить некоторые небуквенные символы, например `'-'` для составных имён/фамилий, или `'\''` для разного рода префиксов (д'Артаньян, О'Тул).

Если во входніх данных строка `input` содержит один объект ФИО, можно использовать метод `Matcher::matches`:

```java
String name = "[А-ЯЁд]'?[а-яё]+(-[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+)?";
String regexp = "(?<surname>" + name + ")\\s+(?<name>" + name + ")\\s+(?<mid>" + name + ")";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    if (input.equals("0")) {
        break;
    }
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Фамилия: " + matcher.group("surname"));
        System.out.println("Имя:" + matcher.group("name"));
        System.out.println("Отчество:" + matcher.group("mid"));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Введенная строка не является ФИО");
    }
}
```

Comment: Понял. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Не проходит только по количеству пробелов Текс== Иван Иванович Иванов вв2ввв=>должно  "Введенная строка не является ФИО". Код обрезает лишнее и подставляет под нужные рамки

Comment: Так у вас в строке может быть одно вхождение ФИО или несколько?

Comment: автотесты подставляют разные варианты ФИО в том числе и ошибочные типа "1111 2222 3333 444" и предадущего который я написал

Comment: то есть может быть несколько ФИО, разделённых `;`?

Comment: нет. только одно ФИО\один тест но эти тесты последовательно подставляют разные варианты ФИО.

Comment: Тогда достаточно использовать `Matcher::matches` вместо `find`, см. обновленный ответ.

Comment: Все отлично прошло) Спасибо. Сможешь объяснить разницу концепции доступно? У тебя отлично получается)

Comment: `matches` сравнивает целую строку, `find` ищет совпадения; если добавить в паттерн/шаблон поиска признаки начала/конца строки `^` и `$`, то `matches(pattern) == find("^" + pattern + "$")`

Comment: Понял.Доступно)

Comment: Если ответ оказался полезен, его можно отметить зелёной галочкой и/или проголосовать за него.